# Oracle PL/SQL - BEFORE INSERT 'table does not exist' error?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm taking my first steps in Pl/SQL and am struggling with triggers. I've tried creating the trigger below but am receiving this error:

> Error at line 2: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

To clarify: I have checked the name of the table over and over, and it does exist. It is also in the same schema as the trigger I'm trying to create. The 'customer_seq.NEXTVAL' refers to a sequence created previously that runs without errors.

The code is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_customer
BEFORE INSERT ON customer
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customer_id VALUES ('c-', customer_seq.NEXTVAL);
END;
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have a table called `customer_id`?  Seems like an unusual name for a table.

Answer (score 1):

You probably intend something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_customer
BEFORE INSERT ON customer
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT customer_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.customer_id
    FROM dual;
END;
```

It is unclear what the purpose of `'C_'` is.  If it is part of the customer id, I would advise you to stick to numbers.

Also note that more recent versions of Oracle support `generated always as identity` -- which is much preferred over defining a sequence and trigger.

Comment: Thanks for this, it cleans up the code a lot. Unfortunately I get the error "Error at line 2: PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" when running it. Will research now.

Comment: You don't need a select. `:NEW.customer_id := customer_seq.NEXTVAL;` will work on any modern Oracle version.

Comment: But, if you desperately want to use SELECT, then `SELECT customer_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.customer_id FROM dual;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I don't know why I always use `INTO` for triggers in Oracle.  It goes back a long, long time.